# How to deserialize JSON in a Windows 8 App seamlessly

Tags: json, windows-runtime, asp.net-web-api, nuget

The Web API Client Library NuGet Packag brings in JSON.NET and some handy extension methods for deserializing JSON like so:

```
response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>().Result
```

But this package is not compatible with Windows 8 App projects. How can I deserialize my JSON objects in the same generic way without this NuGet package?

Comment: Note that accessing .Result might not work for some scenarios and might deadlock your application. Using the await keyword is usually a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by saying "not compatible with Win 8"?

The `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` has been developed to support Win8.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
```

Install just this package, not entire Web API.

You can see the release notes here, in the blog post by Henrik Frystyk Nielsen - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/15/asp-net-web-api-released-and-a-preview-of-what-s-next.aspx

```
The Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries package adds support for formatting 
 content negotiation to System.Net.Http when writing Windows Store Apps. 
It includes support for JSON, XML, form URL encoded data, as well as MIME multipart. 
This package requires Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 8.
```

Comment: "You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Comment: Mh. It´s an "old" blog post but it seems to be still alpha for WinRT. "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Pre" dit it (http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.client).

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 JSON serializers available for Windows Store apps:

- [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) is a part of .NET framework.
- Json.NET is supported as well. You can add it into a Windows Store app project if you install just this package: `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

What exactly are you refering to with "deserialize my JSON objects in the same generic way"?